# Is it possible to represent pieces of two functions with one equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

I'm trying to create a rudimentary weighting system for evaluating how close two numbers are to each other. (This corresponds to string lengths - coding project for work... happy to explain in more detail if you're curious.) The evaluation is simple... x/y. The problem is that when x > y, the number shoots up the graph exponentially. (Orange line in the graph below.) What I want, is when y > 1, the values should ramp back down, like the red line. I can easily put a conditional in my program to change the equation for y values greater than 1, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution. 
**Is there a way to represent the two functions in the graph below for all values x where y<=1 in a single formula?**

[image: two exponential functions]

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean, but perhaps you're looking for $x \mapsto 2^{-|x|}$?

Comment: Oh! Very close, yes. That's the opposite side of the graph that I need, but you helped me figure out the answer!

Comment: Your function and mine agree; the "top half" is give by $x \mapsto 2^{|x|}$. Anyway, I'm glad you found my comment helpful!

Comment: I'm sorry -- when I graphed your original response, I typed it in incorrectly. If you add your response as an answer below, I will be happy to mark it as the correct one. I've deleted my own answer as it had the pointless operation abs(-x).

Comment: There's no need for me to write up a separate answer, you may as well just undelete yours.

Comment: Ok -- If you change your mind and want credit/points, I'm happy to award them to you.

Comment: Try polynomial interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks, Travis. That was exactly what I was looking for.

[image]